# Is it possible to define a binary operation $\mu$ on $(0,1]$ such that ($(0,1], \mu$) is an abelian group?

Tags: group-theory

Is it possible to define a binary operation $\mu$ on $(0,1]$ such that ($(0,1], \mu$) is an abelian group? I tried to define $\mu(a,b) = a+b \pmod 1$. But $0$ is not in $(0,1]$. Thank you very much.

Edit: I think that if we define $\mu(a,b) = a+b \pmod 1$, then $1$ is the identity element. Every element $a$ has an inverse $1-a$. So it is an abelian group. Is this correct?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, yes, I think that $1$ is the identity element. Thank you very much.

Comment: What you've written is exactly correct.  It's not even too much harder to define an abelian group operation on $(0,1)$, though it does take a bit more.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, take a bijective function $f$ from $(0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^\times$ and define $a+b$ as $f^{-1}(f(a)\times f(b))$

Comment: thank you very much. Let $a \in (0,1]$, what is its inverse in $(0,1]$?

Comment: It depends on the function $f$ that you take.

Comment: But it is going to be $f^{-1}(f(a)^{-1})$

Comment: Well, your construction is infinitely better if you want to do some calculations. But this does prove that you can define an operation that makes $(0,1]$ into an abelian group. Of course this same argument works for a ton of different algebraic structures.